# How do I say Taylor Swift's "Loving you is red" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

What I have is **Amoroso tú es rojo**, but when I type this into Google Translate it isn't what I expect and I've learnt to not really trust it. So, is my translation correct?

Comment: The translation is wrong. Could you explain in English what does it mean to love someone like that?

Answer (score 3):

In English there is a tendency to associate feelings with colors that does not exist in Spanish. Feeling blue is "sentirse triste" but in no way is "sentirse azul"

In English blue is sad, green is hope, red is love or happiness but this has no meaning at all in Spanish.

To illustrate here is the second part of the song you mention.

> Losing him was blue like I'd never known
>
> Missing him was dark grey all alone
>
> Forgetting him was like trying to know somebody you never met
>
> But loving him was red
>
> Loving him was red

So I guess the way to say "Loving you is red" in Spanish is something like "Amarte me hace muy feliz" but you can find a thousand better ways to say it than using colors. XD

Good song BTW

Comment: Worse, some of the colors can have different associations.  Calling someone green in Spanish vs in English ....

Comment: In English, "green" means inexperienced, pero ¿què significa si le dices "verde" a alguien?  Es una frase que jamàs he oìdo.

Comment: Depende de que venga antes del verde. Ejemplo, estas verde significa inmaduro pero viejo verde significa acosador

Comment: @MasonWheeler what Matias says, plus ponerse verde (de envidia) or poner verde (a críticas) a alguien.

Comment: Estas verde o eres un viejo verde no hablan de sentimientos que es el tema de la pregunta. En Español hablamos de "verde/morado de envidia", "rojo de vergüenza", "rojo de rabia" pero en inglés frecuentemente el color por si solo expresa el sentimiento por ejemplo en frases como "I'm blue" o en "I saw red".

Comment: @DGaleano De todas formas el OP debería tratar de explicar el concepto. Es bastante pobre la pregunta y creo que le interesa más a los que participamos que al que pregunta...